# Convert JSON data from API to array and display it separately in Laravel and Guzzle HTTP Client?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api, guzzle

I am using API's for fetching data which are in JSON format, I want to convert them into Array and display each ***'name'=>'value'*** pairs separately in Laravel and I am using **Guzzle** Http Client for fetching API data,

Code for fetching data:

```
$pnrNumber = 4238007735;

    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/pnr-status/pnr/'.$pnrNumber.'/apikey/<API-KEY>/');

    $body =  $res->getBody();

    echo $body;
```

Thank you!

Comment: and... what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @matiit I am getting the data in JSON format but I want the data to be separatly stored in different variables **For Example: The JSON data is** ( {"doj": "07-12-2017", "passengers": [{"booking_status": "CNF/S7/15/GN", "no": 1, "current_status": "CNF/-/0/GN"}] } )   I want it to store all values in different variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_decode` function:

`$array = json_decode($body, true);`

Notice that the second parameter is set to `true`, so that the output is an array not a stdClass.